# Serialize whole class with every property

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, serialization, isolatedstorage, datacontractserializer

This is my class which I want to serialize and save to storage.

```
public class Module : ObservableObject
    {
        private int id;

        private MapLocation location;

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { Set(() => Id, ref id, value); }
        }

        public MapLocation Location
        {
            get { return location; }
            set
            {
                Set(() => Location, ref location, value);
            }
        }

     ...
    }
```

My serialize and deserialize methods:

```
    private void Save<T>(T data, string name)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));

        string targetFileName = String.Format("{0}/{1}.dat", FolderName, name);
        if (!storage.DirectoryExists(FolderName))
            storage.CreateDirectory(FolderName);
        try
        {
            using (var targetFile = storage.CreateFile(targetFileName))
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(targetFile, data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            storage.DeleteFile(targetFileName);
        }
    }

    private void Delete(string name)
    {
        string targetFileName = String.Format("{0}/{1}.dat", FolderName, name);
        if (storage.FileExists(targetFileName))
            storage.DeleteFile(targetFileName);
    }

    private T Load<T>(string name)
    {
        T returnValue = default(T);

        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));

        string targetFileName = String.Format("{0}/{1}.dat", FolderName, name);
        if (storage.FileExists(targetFileName))
            using (var sourceStream = storage.OpenFile(targetFileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                returnValue = (T)serializer.ReadObject(sourceStream);
            }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

As you can see I don't use any annotations for xml serialization (used by DataContractSerialier, JsonProperty is used for serialize from Server API). It's working for standart types like int, string, double and list and collections but It don't save MapLocation class or any other class which I tried. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: MapLocation is not serializable because it does not have a public constructor.

Comment: And how can I make it serializable?

Comment: You can't.  If there's no public constructor, you can't make a new MapLocation when you deserialize so you are SOL.  You're going to need to make a class that has the properties of MapLocation that you want to keep, and use that instead.  You'll also note that MapLocationFinderResult.Locations is IReadOnlyList so you can't add multiple results together, either.  Yeah, I don't know why MS locked this stuff down so hard.

Comment: For my app where I needed to serialize location (`Geocoordinate`) I ended up creating my own class, with a public constructor, and a copy constructor to accept  `Geocoordinate`.